# TOP 1 or EXISTS - Which is faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in the database that has almost 2 million records.  I need to find out if more than 1 record is available for a customer.  I have the two following scripts:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ex.exceptionId
FROM exception AS ex
WHERE ex.customerId='{1BF87745-DE00-47FF-9AC0-430BAF87679A}'
AND ex.loanId IS NULL
AND ex.statusType = 'required'
AND ex.exceptionState <> 'N'

SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT ex.exceptionId FROM exception AS ex
WHERE ex.customerId = '{1BF87745-DE00-47FF-9AC0-430BAF87679A}'
AND ex.loanId IS NULL
AND ex.statusType = 'required'
AND ex.exceptionState <> 'N') THEN 1 ELSE 0
END) AS CustomerExceptionCount
```

Which one would be faster and why..?

Many thanks..!

Comment: Wouldn't the first query not answer your question on how many records there are?

Comment: Are these used as subqueries? Because neither of them looks like they'll tell you what you want.

Comment: Did you try to compare the querys with the Server Query Analyzer?

Comment: You have already written both queries. Why not just try it and see? You can look at the execution plans to figure out why.

Comment: Neither of these queries answers the `more than 1 record` question.  They both only answer `1 or more records`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want something like,

```
DECLARE @MoreThanOne Bit;

SELECT @MoreThanOne = CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 2 1
    FROM [exception]
    WHERE [customerId] ='{1BF87745-DE00-47FF-9AC0-430BAF87679A}'
       AND [loanId] IS NULL
       AND [statusType] = 'required'
       AND [exceptionState] <> 'N'
) [FirstTwo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running these queries, you will get the time taken by the query

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT TOP 1 ex.exceptionId
FROM exception AS ex
WHERE ex.customerId='{1BF87745-DE00-47FF-9AC0-430BAF87679A}'
AND ex.loanId IS NULL
AND ex.statusType = 'required'
AND ex.exceptionState <> 'N'
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
GO
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT ex.exceptionId FROM exception AS ex
WHERE ex.customerId = '{1BF87745-DE00-47FF-9AC0-430BAF87679A}'
AND ex.loanId IS NULL
AND ex.statusType = 'required'
AND ex.exceptionState <> 'N') THEN 1 ELSE 0
END) AS CustomerExceptionCount
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```